# Error when uploading MySQL database to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I apologize if this is simple. This seems to be a somewhat common error.

I'm trying to upload the MySQP database to phpMyAdmin and am getting the following error message. From what I read on other posts, it's probably as simple as a comma, but I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated!

SQL query:

```
-- Table structure for table `wp_eaet_commentmeta`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_eaet_commentmeta` (

  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,

  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL said:

> 1046 - No database selected

Comment: It must be realy-really difficult to search for the error message before asking..

Answer (score 2):

As the error says

MySQL said:

1046 - No database selected

Select a database first from list of the databases in phpmyadmin then upload

Comment: jeez. thanks! that helped.